# Access Slim Flash Data in Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

How do I access flash messages that I set in my `Slim` route, in my Twig view? Here is my route:

```
$app->post('/register', function () use ($app) {

    $v = new \Valitron\Validator($_POST);

    $v->rule('required', [
        'username',
        'password',
        'password_confirm',
        'firstname',
        'surname',
        'email',
        'paypal']
    )->message('{field} is required');

    $v->rule('email', ['email', 'paypal'])->message('{field} is not a valid email');
    $v->rule('alpha', ['firstname', 'surname'])->message('{field} can only contain alpha characters');
    $v->rule('alphaNum', ['username'])->message('{field} can only contain alpha characters and numbers');
    $v->rule('equals', 'password', 'password_confirm')->message('Passwords do not match');

    if($v->validate() === false) {
        # How do I access this from within a view
        $app->flash('errors', $v->errors());
        $app->redirect('/register');
    }

    # More code ...
});
```

I have used `session_start()` at the head of my `index.php`. I just can't understand how to access the flash messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the array `$v->errors()` looks like this:

```
array(1) { 
    ["email"]=> string(34) "Email is not a valid email address" 
}
```

You can use this in your view `{{flash.errors}}` and to retrieve the email message: `{{flash.errors.email}}`

Comment: I've tried this, but it's showing NULL. Even though the errors are set. I have tested with `dump` too, same thing: `{{dump(flash.errors)}}`

Comment: What if you do in the '/register' route `var_dump($_SESSION['slim.flash'])`

Comment: `<?php var_dump($_SESSION) ?>` does nothing, and `{{ var_dump($_SESSION) }}` returns an error that the $ is invalid in Twig templates

Comment: Please do the var_dump in PHP not in the twig template.

Comment: I did, I put both in the last comment.

Comment: I dumped in /register controller, and it showed the errors. But they won't display in my Twig template.

Comment: What is the content of $_SESSION?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74815/discussion-between-lolkat-and-tuim).